# upstart job doesn't stop on "service something stop"

Tags: java, scripts, upstart, services

Could you guys please help with with Upstart script ?

For some reason it cannot stop java process on `service something stop`.

service status says `bbb stop/waiting`

I'm trying to run my app which is jar file (java).

Here is how my script looks like

```
description "BBB API service"

# no start option as you might not want it to auto-start
# This might not be supported - you might need a: start on runlevel [3]
start on runlevel [3]
stop on runlevel [!2345]
# stop on shutdown

# if you want it to automatically restart if it crashes, leave the next line in
respawn

script
    cd /home/ubuntu/bbb-server/target
    su -c "/usr/bin/java -jar /home/ubuntu/bbb-server/target/api_standalone.jar" nobody
end script
```

Answer (score 0):

Syntax to [stop](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#stop) Upstart job is

```
stop jobname
```

You might want to check the [Cookbook](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/) section [Run a Java Application](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#run-a-java-application) in addition.